# get each column without using row.find('td:eq(0)')

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How can I get each column in row without using `.find('td:eq(0)')`? I need another way to get each column.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_librarian', function()
{
    var librarianDataRow=$(this).closest('tr');
    var librarianId=parseInt(librarianDataRow.find('td:eq(0)').text());
    var librarianName=librarianDataRow.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    $('#confirm-model-body').text("Are you sure you want to delete "+librarianName+" data");
    $('#confirm-modal').modal({backdrop: 'static'});
    $('#confirm-model-yes-button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/admin/librarian",
            type: "DELETE",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({id:librarianId}),
            success:function (data) {
                if(data.success == true)
                {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(data.message); 
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: don't use jQuery? because a `tr` element has easy ways to "address" `td`'s contained within

Comment: *"i nead another way to get each column"* Why? If you don't tell us, we're likely to give you alternatives that have the same problem.

Comment: it's don't append any problem and work successfully , just i want best way to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use vanilla JS instead if you don't want to use jQuery methods for whatever reason:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_librarian', function() {
  var librarianDataRow = this.closest('tr');
  var librarianId = Number(librarianDataRow.children[0].textContent);
  var librarianName = librarianDataRow.children[1].textContent;
  // ...
```

Could also use

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_librarian', function() {
  var librarianDataRow = this.closest('tr');
  var librarianId = Number(librarianDataRow.cells[0].textContent);
  var librarianName = librarianDataRow.cells[1].textContent;
  // ...
```

Comment: There's nothing non-vanilla about using a library. What you mean is "You could use the DOM directly." The **language** is the same either way.

Comment: There appear to be many, many people distinguish libraries from "Vanilla Javascript" by using exactly that phrase. I think pretty much everyone understands what it means even if, when you break down the phrase, it's not technically precise.

Comment: Yes, just as there are many, many people who misuse other terms. :-) Doesn't mean we have to promulgate it. By using the correct term, you help people who may need to search for other DOM features later.